# Edit user Profiles

Tags: profile, user, edit

I have a problem with some orgs. Normally, I can edit user profiles, e.g. to activate a connected app. Now, I have an org, where these edit-Links aren't there (only delete and duplicate). I'm logged in as a system admin and I should activate a connected app in my own profile, but it's not possible (not any other profile, too). What could be the reason and how can I change it? Btw.: I noticed, that I am not even allowed to change my language in user-settings..??! Appreciate your help...Rainer

[image]

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: Is it a production org, full sandbox, partial, or dev sandbox?

Comment: It's a demo org in my case, at customer it's a production org and Sandbox, same behaviour.